# En un script, ¿cómo puedo mover a otro directorio un archivo que está en el directorio del script?

Tags: linux, bash, script

Tengo un script en una carpeta y en esa misma carpeta muchos archivos. ¿Cómo le digo al script que mueva un archivo que hay en dicha carpeta a otra ubicación?

Comment: No has encontrado nada en Google? Busca por `mover carpetas bash`

Comment: quieres mover una carpeta o un archivo ? o una serie de archivos alojado en una carpeta? o dentro de una carpeta hay mas carpetas y archivos

Comment: @LinuxeroGeek veo que has agregado varías preguntas lo cual es bienvenido pero debes leer como pueden ser recibidas de forma correcta en la comunidad, es importante realices el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio y además obtienes tu primera medalla. Además 

es **muy importante revisar [ask]** que te brinda información para realizar una buena pregunta, esta sea bien recibida en la comunidad

Comment: No añadas el texto "Solucionado" en el título. En su lugar, [acepta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) una respuesta si te fue de utilidad

Answer (score 1):

El comando `mv` sirve para mover archivos entre directorios:

```
#!/bin/bash
mv nombreDelArchivoOrigen /ruta/destino
```

El archivo que quieres mover está en la misma carpeta que el script, por lo que con decirle el nombre del archivo ya lo va a encontrar.

La ruta destino, pon la que quieras.

Comment: lo de mv ya lo se , no es eso a lo que me refiero... toca seguir buscando , Gracias igualmente :)

Comment: @LinuxeroGeek entonces, ¿cuál es tu problema exacto? Edita tu pregunta para clarificarlo.

Comment: una de las opciones del script es que borre un archivo que hay en una ubicacion y lo sustituya por otro que tengo en la carpeta donde esta el script , cuando lo ejecuto da este error ./prueba.sh: línea 1: [: falta un `]'

cp: no se puede efectuar `stat' sobre '/Script OneOnClick/config': No existe el fichero o el directorio
rm: no se puede borrar '/root/.config/i3/config': No existe el fichero o el directorio